# Showing the field of fractions of a domain $D$ is not Noetherian as a $D$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose that $D$ is an integral domain and $F$ its field of fractions, $D \neq F$. I want to show that $F$ as $D$-module is not Noetherian.

*Attempt:* By contradiction, suppose it is. Because $D \neq F$ I can find $d$ which is not in $F$. How to build an ascending chain that leads to a contradiction? I know that the different powers of $d$ are all different from 0 because $D$ is domain. But I get a descending chain, and I want an ascending one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $f \in F \setminus D$, so $f = b/a$, with $b, a \in D$, and $a \ne 0$ not invertible in $D$. We have also $1/a \in F \setminus D$.

Consider the $D$-submodules of $F$ given by
$$
\left\langle \frac{1}{a} \right\rangle \subseteq
\left\langle \frac{1}{a^{2}} \right\rangle \subseteq
\left\langle \frac{1}{a^{3}} \right\rangle \subseteq \dots
$$
All inclusions are proper, because if 
$$
\left\langle \frac{1}{a^{i}} \right\rangle =
\left\langle \frac{1}{a^{i+1}} \right\rangle
$$
then there is $c \in D$ such that
$$
\frac{c}{a^{i}} = \frac{1}{a^{i+1}}
$$
or $c a^{i+1} = a^{i}$, which implies, since $D$ is a domain, $c a = 1$, thus $a$ invertible in $D$.

Comment: Much thanks to both of you, I'm very happy with the answers. By the way, how would you show that $F$ doesn't have a basis as $D$-module? Again, thanks.

Comment: @Robert, start from the fact that any two nonzero elements of $F$ have a nonzero common $D$-multiple.

Comment: Consider $u=a/b,v=c/d$ not zero in $F$. Then, $ub=a, vd=b$ so if I consider $ab=u(bdv)=(ubd)v$ is common D-multiple of $u,v$. And now...

Comment: @Robert, I was thinking of $ubc = ac = vda$. Anyway, so if it has a basis, it consists of one element only. Show that this is impossible.

Comment: It's imposible because then, the field would be the same as its field of fractions. Much thacks! It was short, but hard for me.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.

Since $D$ is not a field, there is some nonzero $d \in D$ such that $d \notin D^\times$. Then $d^{-1} \in F \setminus D$.

Now consider the $D$-modules $d^{-n}D$, $n \in \Bbb N$.